# JavaScript "push" - Basic

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I don't understand why all values change in array when I push object ?
See Chrome console below :

```
 kakebo ={
        title: "",
        date: "",
        status : "", 
        solde: 0,
        entry_up: [
        { name: "", amount:0},
        ],
        entry_down: [
        { name: "", amount:0},
        ]
    };
```

log : {title: "", date: "", status: "", solde: 0, entry_up: Array(1), …}

```
kakebos = [];
```

log : []

```
kakebo.title = "test1"
```

log : "test1"

```
kakebos.push(kakebo);

kakebos
```

log :  `[{…}]0: {title: "test1", date: "", status: "", solde: 0, entry_up: Array(1), …}`

```
kakebo.title = "test2"
```

log : "test2"

```
kakebos.push(kakebo);
```

log : 
kakebos
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 line 1 : 0 : {title: "test2", date: "", status: "", solde: 0, entry_up: Array(1), …}
 line 2 : 1 : {title: "test2", date: "", status: "", solde: 0, entry_up: Array(1), …}

Comment: Please format your code properly by highlighting it in the editor and clicking ctrl+k. Also, you may want to elaborate on what you're asking.

Comment: You are pushing `kabebo` to the array twice, *a reference of the object* -- **they point to the same object**. Modifying the object will in turn be seen by both elements because they are the same reference and point to the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre not pushing two different objects, but actually just one, and change its title.

```
var el = {prop:1}, arr = [];

arr.push(el);//el is added to the array

el.prop = 2;//el is changed

arr.push(el);//el is added a second time
```

You can solve this by either copying the object before adding:

```
arr.push(Object.assign({},el));
```

or you simply set up multiple objects:

```
var el = {prop:1}, arr = [];

arr.push(el);//el is added to the array

var el2 = {prop:2};

arr.push(el2);
```